# I accidentally formatted my external hard drive (HFS+) for TimeMachine (APFS). How can I restore my data?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, external-disk

I have a Western Digital external hard drive formatted in HFS+ where I keep some of my data. I back it up manually. I have another WD disk, which looks very similar, which I use for TimeMachine. So what happened is that I accidentally took the former for the latter.

I plugged the first disk in. A TimeMachine wizard proposed to format it for TimeMachine, and I clicked 'yes' thinking (but not really thinking it through, because I was multitasking) that the file system must have changed with the recent MacOS update, and I could just start TimeMachine anew. A second or so later I realised that I had just erased my first back up disk.

I stopped TimeMachine instantly and unplugged the disk. TimeMachine had formatted the disk in APFS and managed to record 500 Mb of data or so already. I removed the mentioning of this disk from the TimeMachine menu so that TimeMachine would not launch automatically when I plug the disk in again, and I started recovering my data.

I used Disk Drill which was very helpful years ago. It found all the folders and files, and after some time, I recovered them all to a new external drive which I bought. It was formatted in exFAT. I should have formatted it in HFS+ before recovering the date to it, but I was too anxious and did not do that. All the files are there on this disk now, with the same folder order, but I cannot open a single file: the computer says the files I try to open are corrupt.

I am in the process of testing EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard right now as I am writing this. EaseUS shows the folder structure and the files, but I do not know yet whether it will be able to recover the files so that I can open them.

In the meantime, any thoughts on how to recover the data if EaseUS does not work?

Can it be the exFAT format that prevents me from opening the files?

Any other suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It *sounds* like what you may have recovered is mostly the directory structure and possibly **parts** of the files. A data recovery specialist *might* be able to recover the data, or maybe tell you what is left, but it will cost you.